Using Jacobi-Anger expansion to approximate a Gaussian integral
I am trying to perform the following integral,
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2-ib y \sinh{\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)}}dx
\end{equation}
with $b$ and $y$ real and $b> 0$. When $b\to \infty$ the integral becomes a standard Fourier transform,
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2-i xy}dx = e^{-\frac{y^2}{4}}\sqrt{\pi}
\end{equation}
To carry out the integral for finite $b$, I am following a procedure similar to the one outlined in Integral of the product of a Gaussian and a exponential of a hyperbolic function. Making use of the following Jacobi-Anger expansion
\begin{equation}
e^{-i b y \sinh{\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)}}=I_0(by)-2i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n I_{2n+1}(b y)\sinh{\left((2n+1)\frac{x}{b}\right)}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n I_{2n}(b y)\cosh{\left(2n\frac{x}{b}\right)}
\end{equation}
with $I_n(x)$ the modified Bessel functions of the second kind, and the fact that the hyperbolic sine is odd, we have
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\left[I_0(by)+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n I_{2n}(by)\cosh{\left(2n\frac{x}{b}\right)}\right]dx
\end{equation}
Making now use of
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx= \sqrt{\pi}\\
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cosh{\left(ax\right)}dx=e^{\frac{a^2}{4}}\sqrt{\pi}
\end{align}
We arrive at the expression
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I}=\sqrt{\pi}\left[I_0(by)+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{\frac{n^2}{b^2}}(-1)^nI_{2n}(by)\right]
\end{equation}
Plotting this expression as a function of $y$ for different values of $b$, it seems that $\mathcal{I}$ is identical to $e^{-\frac{y^2}{4}}\sqrt{\pi}$ in a region around zero, and quickly switches into a chaotic behavior for large |y|. The value of $|y|$ at which the transition occurs depends on the value of $b$.
Is this behavior intrinsic to the integral $\mathcal{I}$ or is it caused by being outside the domain of convergence of the sum or by the precision of the computer in handling the large numeric cancellations? Is $\mathcal{I}=e^{-\frac{y^2}{4}}\sqrt{\pi}$ for all values of $b$? How can I study rigorously the behavior of $\mathcal{I}$ at large $|y|$?
These are some numeric examples ($\mathcal{I}$ in blue and $e^{-\frac{y^2}{4}}\sqrt{\pi}$ in orange; I am using the first 100 terms in the sum, but taking a larger number of terms does not seem to change these plots):
$b=5$:
$b=5$" />
$b=10$:
$b=10$" />
$b=20$:
$b=20$" />

Is your summation correct? That doesn't look like it converges.

I believe it converges in a region around $y=0$, but I find it difficult to prove. Numerical computation seems to converge. Also, it is possible to show convergence in the limit $b\to \infty$ with $yb$ finite, since $I_0(by)+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{2n}I_{2n}(by)=1$. I think computing the domain of convergence as a function of $b$ is an important piece in answering the question, but I do not see how to do it.
